# Javascript: add function as parameter to predefined callback function

Tags: javascript

I have this code that uses a cordov/phonegap plugin:

```js
var app = { 
   init: function (){
     sensors.getState(app.callback);
   },
   callback: function(state){
     //parameter of this callback function is define by cordova plugin 
     if (state[0] == 0) {
       //execute another function passed as argument because I wwant to change it in other parts of my code
       }
   },
   firstFunction(){
     //execute action 1
     },
   secondFunction(){
    //execute action 2
    }
  
}
```

Now sensors.getState has one argument and is predefined by plugin . I would like to execute a function passed as added argument like:
 sensor.getState(app.callback(firstFunction)) or when i need sensor.getState(app.callback(secondFunction))

Thanks.
IngD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    var app = {
    init: function() {
        sensors.getState(app.callback);
    },
    test: function() {},
    setCallback: function(callback) {
        app.test = callback;
    },
    callback: function(state) {
        app.test();
    },
    firstFunction() {
        alert("firstFunction");
    },
    secondFunction() {
        alert("secondFunction");
    }
};
app.setCallback(app.firstFunction);
app.callback();
app.setCallback(function () { alert("thirdFunction"); });
app.callback();
```

Comment: So in use your Init would look something like init: function() {
        sensors.getState(app.callback);
        app.setCallback(somethinghere);
    }